# Dreamweaver Regex Find and Replace Using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, dreamweaver

I am using a Regular Expression to perform a find and replace with dreamweaver. I am running into some difficulty. This is what I have in my page (note that there is a syntax error because I need an additional parenthesis at the end of the string).

```
$email=htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);      
$name=htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

I am trying to performa a find and replace that will produce this:

```
$email=htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));                                                    
$name=htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
```

This is what I am using to perform the find. It seems to be replacing too much text (it starts with the $_POST from the $email variable, but continues all the way down to the $_POST for the $name variable)

- Find: \$_POST['([^<]*)']
- Replace: $_POST['$1'])

I end up with this:

```
$email=htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);      
$name=htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
```

As you can see, it only fixes the last instance (this is because the find function is selecting both lines from $_POST['email'] all the way to $_POST['name']). Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a question mark to make it non-greedy. Also, you need to escape the [ and ] characters that you want to match.

```
Find: \$_POST\['([^<]*?)'\]
Replace: $_POST['$1'])
```

Or, alternatively, user a ' character instead of a < character to match the value within the quotes:

```
Find: \$_POST\['([^']*)'\]
Replace: $_POST['$1'])
```

Comment: I am getting a regular expression syntax error: "unmatched ) in regular expression". Any ideas?

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!!! It now works perfectly (the alternative method). I'll be marking your answer correct in approximately "7" minutes

Comment: Im about to post a new but similar question. It is slightly more complicated as I messed up the islet function. I will post shortly and include the link here

Comment: Slightly more complicated. Any ideas on this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676555/dreamweaver-regex-find-and-replace-with-regular-expression

Comment: I see someone else helped... don't forget to upvote the answers to your questions too...