# Dreamweaver Regex Find and Replace with Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, dreamweaver, regex-greedy

I have many instances throughout my site where I have inadvertently included the following code:

```
if (isset(htmlspecialchars($_GET['u'])))
```

I need to do a widespread find/replace to turn that code into this:

```
if (isset($_GET['u']))
```

I am trying to use the code below to find with Regular Expressions, but it only comes up if I don't include the htmlspecialchars and parentheses.

- Find: htmlspecialchars(\$_GET['([^']*)'])
- Replace: $_GET['$1']

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` and `[]` need to be escaped.

```
isset\(htmlspecialchars\(\$_GET\['([^']*)'\]\)\)
```

Comment: @subroutes, I am getting a regular expression syntax error - unmatched ) in regular expression

Comment: ok that works but I can't compile it with the whole thing. how would id find this:  isset(htmlspecialchars\(\$_GET\['([^']*)'\]\))

Comment: I forgot to add the isset part in there